Riverpod dependency failing when pub get
I am trying to add Riverpod dependency to my Flutter project but when i try to pub get the error below. How can i resolve this please? It's my first time using riverpod
"Note: meta is pinned to version 1.11.0 by flutter_test from the flutter SDK.
See https://dart.dev/go/sdk-version-pinning for details.
Because riverpod_lint >=2.3.12 <3.0.0-dev.0 depends on analyzer ^6.5.0 which depends on meta ^1.14.0, riverpod_lint >=2.3.12 <3.0.0-dev.0 requires meta ^1.14.0.
And because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on meta 1.11.0, riverpod_lint >=2.3.12 <3.0.0-dev.0 is incompatible with flutter_test from sdk.
So, because riverpod_basics depends on both flutter_test from sdk and riverpod_lint ^2.3.12, version solving failed.
You can try the following suggestion to make the pubspec resolve:

Consider downgrading your constraint on riverpod_lint: flutter pub add dev:riverpod_lint:^2.3.10"

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0
  custom_lint:
  riverpod_lint: ^2.3.12

include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml
analyzer:
  plugins:
    - custom_lint


Run flutter upgrade and after completing go back to the project and try flutter pub get again .

riverpod_lint v2.3.12 requires analyzer with min version 6.5.0 which requires meta with min version 1.14.0.
However, your flutter sdk has a pinned meta version 1.11.0 which is lower than 1.14.0. (Flutter 3.22.1 is using meta 1.12.0)
A temporary workaround would be adding a dependency_overrides to the pubspec.yaml file.
dependency_overrides:
  meta: ^1.14.0

Or use the older riverpod_lint version
dev_dependencies:
  riverpod_lint: ^2.3.10

